# Why I get segfault on array assignment

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I got N more than 1 million, and allocated memory for arrays. But then I try to assign values to array elements, exactly on `i == 263164` I got segmentation fault. What is wrong here?

```
int N = 1<<20;
float *x, *y;
x = (float *)malloc(N);
y = (float *)malloc(N);
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    x[i] = 1.0f;
    y[i] = 2.0f;
}
```

Comment: A `float` does not fit in one byte. You need to allocate `N * sizeof(float)` bytes.

Comment: Oh, I should change allocation to `(float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float))`

Answer (score 0):

On calling `(float *)malloc(N)` I allocated `N` bytes and return pointer to that allocation. When I try to write `N` floats to that array I get segmentation fault because N floats can't fit to N bytes. Instead I should allocate memory like this `(float *)malloc(N*sizeof(float))`

Comment: It is preferable to write the allocation as `y = malloc(N * sizeof *y);`. This avoids repeating the type, and it allocates space for `N` elements of whatever type `y` is—if somebody later edits the code to change the type of `y`, they can make the change in just one place, where `y` is defined, and not have to change it in every `malloc` call. Also, in C (unlike C++), you do not need to cast the result of `malloc`.